# Shopify GraphQL Admin API Query By Nested Attribute Value?

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

Is it possible to query orders by a nested attribute value using the Shopify Admin API? I haven't found anything in the documentation indicating if this is possible or not. Essentially, I want to query all orders for a customer, but only return orders that have an `app.name` value of "Online Store." To query orders with a non-nested attribute (such as displayFulfillmentStatus) is simple enough:

**Query**

```
query ($displayFulfillmentStatus: String!) {
  customer(id: "gid://shopify/Customer/123123123") {
    orders(first: 10, query: $displayFulfillmentStatus) {
      edges {
        node {
          displayFulfillmentStatus
          app {
           name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**GraphQL Variable:**

```
{
  "displayFulfillmentStatus": "UNFULFILLED"
}
```

However, if I wanted to query by the `app.name` value, I don't get any results. Is it because I'm formatting the GraphQL variable incorrectly? Here is what I've tried:

**GraphQL Variable**

```
{
  "appName": "Online Store"
}
```

```
{
  "app": {
    "name": "Online Store"
  }
}
```

I've also tried this without defining GraphQL variables and still haven't had any luck. Am I attempting to do something that isn't possible? I am not too familiar with GraphQL, but based off what I've researched, it does seem possible to filter by nested attribute values. However, the syntax is different than what Shopify uses. So I believe that means Shopify's server would have to be configured to accept an argument of a nested attribute? Does Shopify allow for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if using variables like that is allowed to query. To query the orders you should be able to write `orders(query:"fullfillment_status:unshipped"...`

Answer (score 0):

Online Store is not an App. It is a sales channel. So if you wanted to filter orders based on the sales channel, you have to filter on that. The problem is, Shopify has decided that info is in publication channels, and those are often nil or not set, and GQL does not have the order source_name "web" which is Online Store. So you're caught in never never land right now. Kinda sorta.